# File Name and Extension not respected when sent from .NET Web API to Angular2 App

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

**The Use Case**:
An input field receives a .RDL file on which some actions will be performed. This file then gets sent to a .NET Web Api service where it gets processed and once processing is complete, it returns the processed file to the user. The client is implemented using Angular2.

**View template**

```
<h3 align="center" class="title" onClick="window.location.reload()">
   Converter Utility
</h3>
<div align="center">
   <input type="file" accept=".rdl" (change)="changeListener($event)"/>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input id="replace" name="replace" type="checkbox"> Replace the file?<br>
   <label></label>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="Process" (click)="doProcess()" />
   <br>
   <br>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MainService } from './services/main.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'converter-utility',
  templateUrl: './app/views/main.component.html',
  providers: [MainService],
  styleUrls: ['./app/views/css/main.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  private workableFile: any;

  constructor(
    private mainService: MainService
    ) { }

  changeListener($event): void {
    this.workableFile = $event.target.files[0];
  }

  doProcess() {
    var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    var serv = this.mainService;

    myReader.readAsText(this.workableFile);
    myReader.onload = (e) => {
      serv.passFileUrl(myReader.result)
                    .subscribe((data: any) => { 
                    try 
                    {
                      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, this.workableFile.name);
                    } 
                    catch (err)
                    {
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    window.open(url);
                    }
                  });
    }
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response,ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MainService {
   private projectURL = 'http://localhost:64895/api/Process/RetrieveFile';
   private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });

   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   passFileUrl(result) {
           var json = JSON.stringify(result);
           return this.http.post(this.projectURL, json, {
                                                           headers: this.headers, 
                                                           responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
                           .map((response) => {
                               return new Blob([response.blob()], {type:'application/octet-stream'});
                           });
   }
}
```

**Method on the WebApi that spits out the fixed file**

```
private HttpResponseMessage SaveFile()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(_copyFile.GetCopiedFile.OuterXml);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "FixedDocument.rdl";
    return response;
}
```

**The problem**

The returned file has the following issues which I need a workaround for:

1. The file has a 'file name'  which is a GUID (testing in Chrome). I expect the file name to be FixedDocument.rdl but this is not being passed through to my Angular2 controller.
2. The file also doesnt contain any extension on it and therefore the browser is unsure what to do with it. The file is in XML format.

The content is fine, the fixes are in places just as expected. So, after a discussion with my team, we figured that the problem might be at Angular side Blob class and the Content-Disposition.

How can this be possibly be fixed?

We have attempted using Content-Disposition as suggested in many other posts however, this does not seem to be respected and a GUID is assigned.